# How to get 802.1X credentials with hostapd-wpe?

Tags: wifi, 802.1x

I've been using [hostapd-wpe](https://github.com/OpenSecurityResearch/hostapd-wpe) to create fake access points and trick clients into connecting to them. This plan always worked very well for "normal" WPA2-Enterprise networks, as I've always been able to get the challenge-response data.

However, I've encountered a case where the authentication credentials are sent via 802.1X and I can't manage to see them (in any form) with the usual AP.

The following is the configuration file that I always use with WPA2-Enterprise networks. I've tried slightly modifying it to make it work, but without success.

```
interface=wlan2

ssid=test-wpa2-h
hw_mode=g
channel=11

ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

eap_user_file=hostapd-wpe.eap_user
ca_cert=../../hostapd-wpe/certs/ca.pem
server_cert=../../hostapd-wpe/certs/server.pem
private_key=../../hostapd-wpe/certs/server.pem
private_key_passwd=whatever
dh_file=../../hostapd-wpe/certs/dh

eap_server=1
eap_fast_a_id=101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f
eap_fast_a_id_info=hostapd-wpe
eap_fast_prov=3
ieee8021x=1
pac_key_lifetime=604800
pac_key_refresh_time=86400
pac_opaque_encr_key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
wpa=1
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
```

Comment: Note to reviewers: this question meets the "high effort" qualifier of the "break a specific system" exception. It is clear that OP has put in plenty of effort.